# Django with websockets - Uvicorn + Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, websocket, gunicorn, uvicorn

I am trying to run a Django website with channels activated to use the websocket.
Everything is working fine when using runserver, but things are getting spicy while switching to Nginx + Uvicorn.

here is my /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/myapp/
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 1 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --timeout 300    --bind unix:/home/myapp/myapp.sock myapp.asgi:application


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

here is my /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/home/myapp/myapp.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

and here is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.box 10.42.0.1;
    
    
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location ~ ^/static {
        autoindex on;
        root /home/myapp;
    }

    location ~ ^/ {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/myapp/myapp.sock;
    }
    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/myapp/myapp.sock;
    }
}
```

Nginx is running, the socket and gunicorn an issue with gunicorn showing the below error message.

```
Jul 07 11:14:11 hostname gunicorn[1825]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
Jul 07 11:14:11 hostname gunicorn[1825]:     self._setup(name)
Jul 07 11:14:11 hostname  gunicorn[1825]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in _setup
Jul 07 11:14:11 hostname  gunicorn[1825]:     raise ImproperlyConfigured(
Jul 07 11:14:11 hostname  gunicorn[1825]: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the envir>
Jul 07 11:14:11 hostname  gunicorn[1825]: [2021-07-07 11:14:11 +0800] [1825] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1825)
Jul 07 11:14:12 hostname  gunicorn[1822]: [2021-07-07 11:14:12 +0800] [1822] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Jul 07 11:14:12 hostname  gunicorn[1822]: [2021-07-07 11:14:12 +0800] [1822] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

When I am trying to reach my website, I have the page "Welcome to nginx!" and impossible to get the pages from my site (logical as Gunicorn can't get Django running)

I also attach my /home/myapp/asgi.py file

```
"""
ASGI config for myapp project.

It exposes the ASGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/asgi/
"""
import os
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
import myapp.routing
import MyApp.routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings')
django.setup()

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack( URLRouter( MyApp.routing.websocket_urlpatterns ) ),
    # Just HTTP for now. (We can add other protocols later.)
})
```

Anyone would get an idea of what is going on and where I am missing something?

thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have managed to fix it.
In the asgi.py file, I am importing some external modules, and settings.py must be loaded first.
I have added the below 2 lines at the top of my asgi.py

```
import django
django.setup()
```

before all the imports, and it seems to work so far.